# (#200) Access to this data is temporarily disabled for non-active accounts due to changes we are making to the Facebook Platform

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

Programmers

I'm trying to fetch Facebook page posts by API. But it showing me following error message:

> (#200) Access to this data is temporarily disabled for non-active accounts due to changes we are making to the Facebook Platform

I have tried **Facebook graph explorer** and its working fine over there while using account access token but not working with APP access token. If anybody have any idea about this please help your answers would be very appreciated.

Best Regards
Gurdeep

Comment: Thanks for your response. I was checked that question before posting my question. I have posted again because I didn't find any proper solution over there so I thought maybe I'll get more good answers.

Comment: please don´t repost questions just because there was no proper answer in another thread so far. it got posted only 8 hours ago.

Comment: Okay luschn. I will take care of things in future :)